# Orthogonal matrix to symmetrize a complex 2x2 matrix.

Tags: matrices

I need to find a unitary matrix $G$ such that given a 2x2 complex matrix $A$

$$GA = A'$$    where $A'$ is symmetric.

I tried to use

$$G = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} \bar{c} & -\bar{s} \\ s & c \end{pmatrix}$$

with $c = \cos(\theta) + i \cos(\phi) $ and $s = \sin(\theta) + i \sin(\phi)$

and then I expanded the equation $ A'_{21} = A'_{12} $ but I have not been able to find a suitable result for $ G $.

Any ideas/help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your $G$ is $\sqrt{2}$ times a **unitary** matrix. It is not orthogonal. Not even a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question following your suggestions.